# Whats is the difference between repository_dispatch and workflow_dispatch in Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Please explain the difference between these 2 event triggers with some real world example.

Comment: Both allow to trigger workflows manually. To trigger specific workflows in a repository (for test, backup, expreriences...) use the `workflow_dispatch` event. To trigger more than one workflow in a repository (for example, based on another repository event) and create custom events (based on specific inputs not present in github context, but created somewhere else (ci/cd, scripts, etc...)) and event types, use the `repository_dispatch` event.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, [`repository_dispatch` events may only be read on the default branch](https://github.community/t/how-to-trigger-repository-dispatch-event-for-non-default-branch/14470)

See:

- [this example](https://gist.github.com/br3ndonland/f9c753eb27381f97336aa21b8d932be6) (or [this one](https://gist.github.com/riggaroo/d828c5ffecf261d3ccc7bde89817dba5)) using [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_dispatch)
- [this example](https://gist.github.com/ciiqr/31af63601a4b52a05133cf2c87e022e3) with [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#repository_dispatch)

For the latter, from [William Villeneuve](https://github.com/ciiqr) :

```sh
# TODO: replace :token, :user, and :repo
curl -H "Authorization: token :token" \
    -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/dispatches" \
    -d '{"event_type": "awesomeness", "client_payload": {"foo": "bar"}}'
```

```yaml
name: example-client-payload-action
on: repository_dispatch
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - run: 'echo "field: ${{ github.event.client_payload.foo }}"'
      - run: 'echo "payload: ${{ toJson(github.event.client_payload) }}"'
      - run: echo baz
        if: github.event.action == 'baz'
```

As [seen here](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-ltw/552b90800b07c22e4a83dfa68ada6318):

> Just posting here since it doesn't seem to be documented - you can also specify a list of types to trigger on:

```yaml
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - manual-trigger-mytest
      - manual-trigger-all
```

From "[Manually Trigger A GitHub Actions Workflow](https://goobar.dev/manually-trigger-a-github-actions-workflow/)"

Comment: For workflow_dispatch also: "This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch."  https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim But actually if you have same workflow file in both branch, you can run the workflow against the non-default branch.